# Check whether user visited website earlier

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if same User visited web site!?! How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821431/check-if-same-user-visited-web-site-how)

How can I check if User came to my website eariler anytime between one week. how to check the cookies and searh for my website and then do something.

basically my aim is to check with the keyword, is there any way to do this.**basically i want to search my website from user browsing activities**

let me clear more, its bit confusing...ok

for example user checked my website in 21/07/12, after that he visited 10 other websites. 
now today 2/8/12 user visited my wesbite again, how to know that the user perviously visited my website on 21/07/12. this can be track by fetching keyword or full website link.

**this should be done without storing data (IP ect), looking something its reads from log files or from cookies.**

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. How accurate you want this tracking to be, as cookies can be deleted by user. and more importantly WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED TILL NOW ?

Comment: not duplicate...i have read so many...not found best answer...

Comment: @DhruvPathak read some articles and some posts...but not got what is required....basically i want to search my website from user browsing activities.

Comment: Ok, after the edit, that's a *very* different question. Answer: use google analytics.

Comment: Yea u should try using a google analytics API or a MySQL query to record what pages users go on.

Comment: @ReelMark I disagree. This is a duplicate. The same answer would work for you except changing the timespan from 30 mins to 1 week. If you aren't going to use mysql then the answer is still fine - if the cookie is set and the date set is less than a week old then you will know. However users can delete cookies, change IP addresses, etc so there is no 100% guaranteed way to know. Not even having users log in is truly 100%.

Comment: @Nicholosophy thanks but! i dont want to store any data in database...purely i want to get it either from cookies or from log files...it would be fun!

Comment: @ReelMark As I mentioned, you can use cookies without the database. There is no way you will be able to access client-side log files. If any technology (web browser, language, etc) allowed that there would be (rightly) an uproar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a database table to store user's visits.

```
user_visits // table name
v_id(int) // the unique ID
v_user_id(int) // the user ID
v_post_id(int) // the post id for the page that the user visited
v_user_ip(VARCHAR) // the user IP
v_user_browser(VARCHAR) // the user agent
v_date(TIMESTAMP) // when and what time did the user visited the page
```

Then you can use MYSQL statements to sort it out. Better yet, use google analytics

Comment: that is not the case i wanna get it from cookies or log files....hopfully windows store all log/activies...need to get from there....

Comment: Not. Going. To. Happen. There is no way that I would allow a website to scrape my computer's log files. It's not even possible because it is such a security and privacy issue.

Comment: "hopfully windows store all log/activies...need to get from there.... "..this sounds scary

Comment: this sound scary but shall be very interesting topic...MY SEARCH will not stop...lol